# Using variables in an fql query

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-fql

Having some problems with syntax here. Trying to get like counts on any page using a variable like so:

```
$url = "http://www.my-domain.com"
$result = $facebook->api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => 'SELECT  total_count from link_stat  where  url ="$url";
));
$fb_fans = $result[0]['total_count'];
```

However it works when I replace $url with the actual value as such:

```
$result = $facebook->api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => 'SELECT  total_count from link_stat  where  
    url ="http://www.my-domain.com";
));
$fb_fans = $result[0]['total_count'];
```

Can someone tell me what I am obviously over looking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = "http://www.my-domain.com"
$result = $facebook->api(array(
    "method" => "fql.query",
    "query" => "SELECT  total_count from link_stat  where  url ='".$url."'"
));
$fb_fans = $result[0]['total_count'];
```